# How to prevent terms of condition "Agree" modal box to appear in every page?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to create several pages in WordPress that will display TOS message. If user click "Agree" one time then the other pages shouldn't display the message again. I am using WordPress custom template page in the Child Theme folder.

Comment: Set a cookie when they agree.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to surround the TOS language with a php if statement which checks for the existence of a cookie, maybe named 'seen_tos'. Then add a javascript function whch fires on the 'Agree' button click and saves a cookie using JavaScript, as shown here:

[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)